# Model Current Source based on Voltage Sensor in Circuit Simulator

Tags: ltspice, simulation, current-source

I wanted to simulate a Current Source whose Current depends on the Voltage measured at another location in Circuit (like a voltage Sensor).

For example my source will deliver 100mA Power when the Sensor is 1V and will linearly increase when the Sensor reached 1.5V. I want to provide a lookup table of Current vs Voltage Sensor.

Any ideas of how I can acheive it.

I am presently using LT Spice for my hobby project but I can easily switch to another one as long it is free for hobby projects.

Comment: Voltage dependent current source is what you are looking for.

Comment: When you bring up the component browser look for `g`, or `g2`. Also, don't be afraid of the manual (`F1`). It may be spartan with the words but, it's there to help (in particular: *LTspice > Circuit Elements > ...*).